# How to write in a file from keyboard input in java?

Tags: java, file-io

I wrote a program to write in a file...

```
package iofile;
import java.io.*;
public class WriteFile {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s;
        File file=new File("C:\\Users\\Rajesh\\oacert\\Learn\\src\\iofile\\raj.txt");

        InputStreamReader isr=new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(isr);
        try{
        PrintWriter pr=new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true)));
        System.out.println("enter to write in a file...");
        s=br.readLine();
        while(s!=null){
            pr.println(s);
            s=br.readLine();
        }
        pr.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){

        }


    }

}
```

But it's unable to write anything in raj.txt. What's causing this? Thanks in Advance
NOTE: raj.txt exists in the mentioned directory...

Comment: How can `s` ever be `null`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer If the user presses the end-of-file char, ctrl-D on UNIX.

Comment: In the `catch` clause, you should print a stack trace. Otherwise you will silently absorb all exceptions and not see what's going wrong. Add the line `e.printStackTrace();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Use write method.
2. Put an end condition, such as s.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")
3. Call method flush;

Try the following code.

while(!s.equalsIgnoreCase("Exit")){

```
            pr.write(s);
            pr.write("\n");
            s=br.readLine();
        }
        pr.flush();
        pr.close();
```

Comment: Worked!! But why it is necessary to use write method? print method of PrintWriter could have done it??

Comment: Actually, it is unnecessary to use write method here. The print methods seem to be wrappers around the write methods.  See print method in PrintWriter source code.     public void print(String s) {
        if (s == null) {
            s = "null";
        }
        write(s);
    }    In addition, method print supports more types of parameters

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `s` can ever be `null` in your code. You should better use a terminating string to exit the program. Try replacing this:

```
    while(s!=null){
```

with

```
    while(!s.equals("exit")){
```

and enter 'exit' to terminate the loop

Comment: `s` will be `null` if the program reaches the end of `System.in`. This can happen in several ways. For instance, the program can be run with input piped from a file or the user can enter an end-of-text character from the console (ctrl-D in Unix; ctrl-Z in Windows).